How to use torch.unique to filter duplicate values, calculate an expensive function, map it back, and then calculate the gradient?
I'm trying to optimize a computation in PyTorch by first identifying the unique elements of a tensor, applying an expensive function (e.g., torch.exp) to these unique elements only, and then mapping the results back to the original tensor's shape to calculate the gradient with respect to the original tensor.
My motivation is to avoid redundant calculations of the expensive function for duplicate values in the input tensor, which would significantly improve performance.
Here's the code snippet that demonstrates my approach, but it results in an error since unique is not differentiable:
import torch

inputs = torch.rand(100)
inputs = torch.round(inputs, decimals=2)
inputs.requires_grad_(True)

unique_inputs, inverse_indices = torch.unique(inputs, return_inverse=True)
print(f"There are {unique_inputs.numel()} unique elements.")

unique_exp = torch.exp(unique_inputs)
full_exp = unique_exp[inverse_indices]

torch.autograd.grad(full_exp[0], inputs) # <-- Error here

Is there another way I can do that?

You can do this with a custom backward function:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class UniqueForward(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, inputs):
        unique_inputs, inverse_indices = torch.unique(inputs, return_inverse=True)
        unique_counts = torch.bincount(inverse_indices)
        ctx.save_for_backward(inverse_indices, unique_counts)
        ctx.input_shape = inputs.shape
        return unique_inputs, inverse_indices

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_unique, grad_inverse):
        inverse_indices, unique_counts = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_inputs = grad_unique[inverse_indices]
        grad_inputs = grad_inputs / unique_counts[inverse_indices]
        return grad_inputs

class EfficientFunction(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, function):
        # function should be a callable element-wise function
        super().__init__()
        self.function = function
        self.unique_forward = UniqueForward.apply
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        unique_inputs, inverse_indices = self.unique_forward(inputs)
        unique_results = self.function(unique_inputs)
        full_results = unique_results[inverse_indices]
        return full_results

The EfficientFunction module should work for any case where 1) the inputs have duplicated values and 2) the function in question applies an element-wise operation.
Example:
def expensive_function(x):
    # use exp as example of expensive function
    return torch.exp(x)

efficient_function = EfficientFunction(expensive_function)

# test efficient version
inputs = torch.rand(100)
inputs = torch.round(inputs, decimals=2)
inputs.requires_grad_(True)

outputs = efficient_function(inputs)
loss = outputs.mean()
loss.backward()

# test naive version
inputs2 = inputs.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
naive_results = expensive_function(inputs2)
naive_loss = naive_results.mean()
naive_loss.backward()

# compare gradients 
torch.allclose(inputs.grad, inputs2.grad)


Thank you. However, this approach only functions correctly when we use loss = outputs.mean(). If we try loss = outputs[0]; loss.backward(), it will fail because it will compute the loss for multiple outputs. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

In your example, you use an element-wise function. If you want to backprop from outputs[0], then you only have to compute the function of inputs[0]

I'm looking to compute the Jacobian matrix (which essentially represents the gradient for each output independently). Unfortunately, the current code isn't suitable for this task. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

If you want the jacobian you can compute that via torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(efficient_function, inputs), however this is inconsistent with your stated framework of loss = outputs[0]. It is unclear what you are asking for.

The jacobian calculated this way is not identical:
jac = jacobian(efficient_function, inputs); jac2 = jacobian(expensive_function, inputs); print(torch.allclose(jac, jac2))
will print False.

Looks like the jacobian operation is doing something different from a standard backwards. If you're just looking for the vector you get from backward you can backward from outputs directly without averaging it - outputs = efficient_function(inputs), outputs.backward(torch.ones_like(outputs))

That helped, thank you!
